# How can i implode each row and display on a table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to display how many keys and value in each row in a `td` tag, but in my second `td` tag display the first and second row.. and then also the third...

How can I display first row in a first `td` tag, and 2nd row in 2nd `td` tag? Here's my code so far:

```
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Rows</th>        
     </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>     
<?php  
$query  = "SELECT from_monday, from_tuesday, from_wednesday,from_thursday, from_friday, to_monday, to_tuesday,to_wednesday, to_thursday, to_friday from tabletest ORDER BY survey_id DESC LIMIT 4";           

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

if($result === FALSE) {     die(mysql_error()); }

while($details = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{ 
    $newArray = array_count_values($details) ; 
    foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) 
    {       
         $newValue = $value/2;
         $key      = trim(addslashes($key));        
         $newValue = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $newValue);
         $myurl[]  = "['".$key."', ".$newValue."]"; 

    }

     echo "<tr><td>"; 
     echo implode(",", $myurl);  
     echo "</td></tr>";
}

?>        
       </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Do yourself a good formatting.

Comment: how about some good English grammar ? :-)

Comment: Does any of the values contain any HTML? Other than that I see no reason your code wouldn't work. Perhaps try to post the actual HTML output created by the snippet?

Comment: output in 1st td tag  ['car', 5],['train', 4],['jeep', 1]  but on 2nd td tag display like this "['car', 5],['train', 4],['jeep', 1],['car', 6],['train', 4]"... the 1st and 2nd row display all in 2nd td tag

Comment: i want the 1st row in a table display in a first td tag, then the 2nd row in the 2nd td tag.....

Comment: `$newArray = array_count_values($details) ; $myurl=array();` Try this

Comment: Just reset array `$myurl = array();` , check answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing data in an array it mean it will contain previous values as well on each loop iteration, you need to reset the array on each iteration

```
$myurl = array();
```

try following code

```
<?php  
$query  = "SELECT from_monday, from_tuesday, from_wednesday,from_thursday, from_friday, to_monday, to_tuesday,to_wednesday, to_thursday, to_friday from tabletest ORDER BY survey_id DESC LIMIT 4";           

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

if($result === FALSE) {     die(mysql_error()); }

while($details = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{ 
    $newArray = array_count_values($details) ; 
    $myurl = array();
    foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) 
    {       
         $newValue = $value/2;
         $key      = trim(addslashes($key));        
         $newValue = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $newValue);
         $myurl[]  = "['".$key."', ".$newValue."]"; 

    }

     echo "<tr><td>"; 
     echo implode(",", $myurl);  
     echo "</td></tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: It works... thankz man! Im trying to put the fetch data in a google pie chart... So I hope I can do it now...